# To display actual attribute instead of its id

Tags: database, yii

I have two tables Question and Status. Quesion table is having relation with status table. Question table is having status id as field. i want to display actaul status instead of its id....So what i should do?

Comment: You should JOIN your Question table with Status table and retrieve the status name in place of status ID. But that depends on how [tag:yii] is being used.

Comment: thanx for your quick reply. I am having following relation on Question controller.=  'questionStatus' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Qbstatus', 'QuestionStatusId'),         So can you please tell me how to display actual status.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the right relations:

a) Grab a **Qestion** object:

```
$question = Question::model()->findByPk(1); // e.g
```

*Above is just an example, you could get the object or array of objects using the availble varations of yii active record functions, but let say you got the object of the Question model*

b) You use the relation to retrive active record corresponding **Status** object:

```
$status = $question->status; // where status is the name of the relation
```

c) Now you have a status object, meaning it's an object of your **Status** model. You can use the default attribute getter to do:

```
$status->name; //where name is the attribute you want to get from your status table
```